# How to prove $(p \to (p \lor q)) \equiv\operatorname{True}$

Tags: logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I know how to prove the expression $(p \to (p \lor q))$ being a tautology using truth table. I would also like to know how to prove it using algebraic methods.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just draw truth table, or use $(p\to q)\equiv(\~p∨q)$.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a statement, you don’t need to prove $\alpha\equiv \operatorname{True},$ it is enough to prove $\alpha.$

Comment: You mean $(\lnot p)\lor q$, right, @Nightflight?

Comment: Oh Yes... In my book,they used ~p instead of yours...

Comment: What system are you/do you want to use? In sequent calc it's $P\vdash P$, $P\vdash (P\lor Q)$, $\vdash (P\to(P\lor Q))$ - i.e. it's disjunction introduction. Or do you want to use metalogic? Assume for reductio that there exists an interpretation that makes $v(P\to(P\lor Q))=0$. Hence, $v(P)=1$ and $v(P\lor Q)=0$. $v(P\lor Q)=0$ when $v(P)=v(Q)=0$, which contradicts $v(P)=1$. Thus, $P\to(P\lor Q)$ is true for all interpretations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}(p\to(p\lor q))&\equiv(\bar{p}\lor(p\lor q))\\&\equiv((\bar{p}\lor p)\lor q)\\&\equiv(\top\lor q)\\&\equiv\top\end{align}$$

Therefore, $$(p → (p ∨ q))$$ is a tautology.

Comment: Thank you so much!